# Converting object properties to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, converters

I'm getting output that looks like this:

```
{'1536135941922': 'true',
 '1536135962942': 'false',
 '1536135986966': 'false',
 '1536135989968': 'true'}
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
[{'1536135941922': 'true'},
 {'1536135962942': 'false'},
 {'1536135986966': 'false'},
 {'1536135989968': 'true'}]
```

So my front can consume it. What is the way that I can convert it?

Answer (score 25):

You can use `Object.entries()` and `.map()` methods to get the desired output:

```js
let data = {
  '1536135941922': 'true',
  '1536135962942': 'false',
  '1536135986966': 'false',
  '1536135989968': 'true'
};
  
let result = Object.entries(data).map(( [k, v] ) => ({ [k]: v }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 5):

You could map the entries of the object by using new objects.

Methods:

- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```js
var object = { '1536135941922': 'true', '1536135962942': 'false', '1536135986966': 'false', '1536135989968': 'true' },
    array = Object.entries(object).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }));
  
console.log(array);
```

With [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
var object = { '1536135941922': 'true', '1536135962942': 'false', '1536135986966': 'false', '1536135989968': 'true' },
    array = Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(pair => Object.fromEntries([pair]));
  
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a one-liner with `Object.entries` and `Array.map`:

```js
const data = {'1536135941922': 'true',
  '1536135962942': 'false',
  '1536135986966': 'false',
  '1536135989968': 'true'};
const convert = (object) => Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));
console.log(convert(data));
```

What is your backend set-up? I was assuming Node since you tagged with *javascript*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP you can create object for object and push them to an array. After that, you can convert the array object to json with `json_encode` functions and return it to your front.